# GrGen.NET: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Tags: .net, graph, transformation

I get this exception when I run a transformation in GrGen.NET. I could narrow it down to this minimal example:

**Rule set:**

```
rule createNode : (Node) {
    modify {
        newNode:Node;
        return(newNode);
    }    
}

rule deleteAny {
    :Node;
    replace{}
}
```

**Sequence set:**

```
(myVariable) = createNode
deleteAny[*]
```

P.S.: GrGen.NET is a quite popular graph transformation library (check it out on http://grgen.net) based on the .NET-framework. It would be cool if someone could define a Tag for GrGen.NET, I don't have enough reputation :-). Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this bug comes from underneath from GrGen. The problem is the variable `myVariable` that contains the created node from the rule `createNode`.

When the node should be deleted using `deleteAny`, it's deleted from the graph but still somehow trapped in this variable. A simple workaround is to assign an arbitrary value to this variable, e.g. `myVariable = 0`, before the nodes are getting deleted.

It's a hack, but will do until this bug is fixed.